# How has this post contained a tag before it was created?

Tags: support, tags

So I was looking at the [grapecity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grapecity) tag, which, according to [the info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grapecity/info), was created 16 hours ago:

[image]

But then I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22463032/revisions), which seemingly had the tag since creation, i.e. for the past ~2 months.

[image]

How is this possible? What happened here?

I've seen this happen before in the case of a undeleted post, but this post wasn't (un)deleted.

The tag doesn't appear to have been removed from that post at any point.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that this tag was burned once before, and someone tried to put it back.  It's possible that the Tag Wiki entry can still exist on a burned tag.

Comment: To add insult to injury, many of these questions already had the [componentone] tag on them, which arguably is a marginally useful tag.  [grapecity] is just redundant.  One question didn't even have anything to do with ComponentOne, but it had three componentone related tags on it.  I removed all instances of grapecity.

Comment: I see [one user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3331861/nilay-vishwakarma) suggested a lot of the edits to add [tag:grapecity] to questions. Should we do something about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That date to the right is not when the *tag* was created, but when the *tag wiki* was created. The info page is a page specifically dedicated to the tag wiki and its excerpt. Those stats are when the wiki was created, how many times the wiki has been edited, and how many times the wiki has been viewed. The stats have nothing to do with the physical tag itself.